# How to localize structures HTML views in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, html, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-views

I have a multi-language website and views content (including the markup) can differ from language to language. That's why I cannot just localize strings and put them into resources.

For example, my view in Russian:

```
<div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
        <img src="~/Images/CardHeaders/Business_CreditsSME.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        Text
    </div>            
</div>
```

View in English:

```
<p>Text</p>
```

I see two ways to localize this:

1. Create Page.cshtml and Page.en.cshtml, and create a custom `LocaleView()` method in controller which will use the localized view files.

   - The problem is that Views do not always differ. It means that sometimes I will duplicate the markup.
2. Copy all the HTML markup in my resources as it is, and use `Html.Raw(Resources.PageView)`.

   - It is not convenient to create, modify or read HTML which is located in a resource flies
   - Moreover, I do not like `Html.Raw` method at all and prefer not to use it anywhere

How do you localize large views of different structures?

Comment: only way i can think of is to have dirty code in controller method to have a switch case and return the required view.

Answer (score 1):

I have combined two solutions.

1. I have overriden `View` method in my base controller so that it looks for the existent localized view. Now, **if my views differ too much**, I simply create `View.en.cshtml` file and it is automatically being processed by a controller:

   ```
   public abstract class BaseController : Controller
   {
       protected override ViewResult View(string viewName, string masterName, object model)
       {
           if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName)) 
               viewName = (string)RouteData.Values["action"];

           string localizedViewName = $"{viewName}.{CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name}";
           bool hasLocalizedView = ViewEngines.Engines
               .FindPartialView(ControllerContext, localizedViewName)
               .View != null;

           return base.View(hasLocalizedView ? localizedViewName : viewName, masterName, model);
       }
   }
   ```
2. **If my views have the same structure**, then I don't create separate files, but simply use the same view with localized strings within it like this:

   ```
   <div class="card">
       <div class="card-image">
           <img src="~/Images/CardHeaders/Business_CreditsSME.jpg" />
       </div>
       <div class="card-content">
           @GlobalResources.LocalizedText
       </div>            
   </div>
   ```

The structure now looks like:

```
- Views
-- About
--- History.cshtml
--- History.kk.cshtml
--- History.en.cshtml
--- Vacancies.cshtml
```

where `Vacancies.cshtml` file uses resources to localize a page, and `History*` files are localized like a plain text without resources.

Answer (score 0):

Awesome question!

Between these two option the first one look a little bit better.

But one thing that I usually do. It's created an HTML helper to locate the localised view.

So, you will be able to use it on the view like this:

```
@Html.RenderLocale("YourView", ...);
```

Then, in your RenderLocale, you change the file path to the view that the user wants.

```
public static string RenderLocale(this HtmlHelper helper, string target, ...)
{
     var filePath = this.getLocaleFilePath(target); //it returns yourView.cshtml or yourView.ru.cshtml
     return this.Action(filePath); // it renders or performs the action you want     
}
```